# How to retrieve selected value from selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, selectonemenu

I need to get the value which I have selected from a selectOneMenu in JSF. I used an ArrayList and I am holding data in it.

```
<h:outputText value="Meslek : " />
    <h:selectOneMenu value="meslek">
        <f:selectItems id="meslek7" value="#{comyon.selectıtem}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And this is my bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "comyon")
@RequestScoped

public class ComponentYonetim {

private String ad,soyad,cinsiyet;
private String sonuc = "";
private ArrayList<SelectItem> selectıtem = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
private String donenMeslek = "";

public ComponentYonetim() {
    selectıtem.add(new SelectItem("Asker"));
    selectıtem.add(new SelectItem("Mühendis"));
    selectıtem.add(new SelectItem("Doktor"));
    selectıtem.add(new SelectItem("Öğrenci"));
    selectıtem.add(new SelectItem("Serbest meslek"));
    selectıtem.add(new SelectItem("Polis"));

}

public void yazdir(){
    if(this.ad.isEmpty() || this.soyad.isEmpty()){
        sonuc+="Lütfen boşluk bırakmayınız!";
    }
}

//setters and getters...

}
```

It's showing the ArrayList data but I can't get value from there. How can I get the value from this selectOneMenu with javaBean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read those tutorials:

1. [Mkyoung selectOneMenu tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-dropdown-box-example/)
2. [Mkyong converter tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)

Basically you should select value container for selectOneMenu tag. it means that it should look like:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{comyon.selectedItem}">
   <f:selectItems id="meslek7" value="#{comyon.selectıtem}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and if you need to pass a object not string you should use converter. Look at the links on the top.

Comment: Thansk for your help. Links helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Although what you choose in your drop-down list, the item's value will be the frist line

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{meslek}">
```

So, let's declare a variable with name "meslek" and getter/setter to use the value.

```
private String meslek;
```